# SQL Server slow query to get average

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I normally work with MySQL databases, and I am currently encountering some issues on a query towards a SQL Server database.

I'm trying to get the average of a column, grouped by day. This takes anywhere from 20-30 seconds, even if its just returning a few hundred rows.

The table however contains a couple million entries. I'm sure this has got something to do with the indexing properties, but I just can't seem to figure out the correct solution here.

So the query goes like:

```
select 
    [unit_id], 
    avg(weight) AS avg, 
    max(timestamp) AS dateDay 
from 
    [measurements] 
where 
    timestamp BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-10-04' 
group by 
    [unit_id], CAST(timestamp AS DATE) 
order by 
    [unit_id] asc, [dateDay] asc
```

I have set up a nonclustered index containing the unit_id, weight and timestamp fields.

Comment: maybe the cast for the timestamp is the problem, did you try if it makes a difference?

Comment: If you do not need order by, remove it.

Comment: Removing both the cast, and the ordering still results in a 25 second query

Comment: DId you check execution plan, Is your query using your index at all.

Comment: Show us the plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: there is a option in sql which gives you to used resources for each operation. You could use it by pressing CTRL-L. This can inform you which operation use how much resources and which operation need reworking. If you inform about most heavy operations, we could try to help in here to.

Comment: Im sitting on a mac using SQLPro for MSSQL at the moment. Trying to see if there is a way to get the execution plan from it

Comment: What exactly does the index look like?  i.e. column order

Comment: Also, read this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179325(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: If you can't get the plan then at least post the table structure and the indexes along with approximate row count.

Comment: @OleHaugset    SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON

Comment: Thanks for the tip @etsa. Finally managed to get the execution plan xml, but the pastetheplan feature posted further up won't aknowledge it. Shared the output here: https://codeshare.io/5OJ7mg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select unit_id, avg(weight) AS avg, max(timestamp) AS dateDay 
from measurements m
where timestamp BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-10-04' 
group by unit_id, CAST(timestamp AS DATE) 
order by unit_id asc, dateDay asc;
```

Under reasonable assumptions about your data, it is going to have similar performance in either MySQL or SQL Server.  Your `WHERE` is not highly selective.  Because of the inequality, SQL Server cannot make use of an index for the `GROUP BY`.

An index on `measurements(timestamp, unit_id, weight)` might benefit the query on either database.  There might be some fancy ways to get SQL Server to improve the performance.  But both it and MySQL will need to take the rows matching the `WHERE` clause and aggregate them (using a hash-based algorithm in all likelihood in SQL Server and using a filesort in MySQL).

Comment: Thanks for an informative answer, and for the index tip. The index actually put the query right under 10 seconds, which is fine enough since its a query for generating a report. Ill maybe revisit this for some further optimizing later on :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely the CAST in the group by.  Though you don't say it explicitly, I'm assuming Timestamp is a DateTime value, which is why you CAST to Date in the group by clause.  The problem is that the calculated value produced by CAST isn't indexed.

If it's your system, and this query is something done frequently, I'd add a new column of type Date to store just the day, and index that.  If you can't, select out the values in the date range you're interested in, with the date casted to Date, into a temp table or CTE, then group by the date.

Or, even try this, just to pull the CAST out of the Group By clause:

```
select 
    [unit_id], 
    avg(weight) AS avg, 
    dateDay 
from (
    select  [unit_id], 
            CAST(timestamp as Date) [dateDay],
            weight
        from [measurements] 
        where 
            timestamp BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-10-04' 
    ) x
group by 
    x.[unit_id], x.[dateDay]
order by 
    x.[unit_id] asc, x.[dateDay] asc
```